# How to display only invoice created date in invoice template and format date?

Tags: invoice

I want to display invoice created date in invoice e-mail template.
I am using {{var invoice.created_at}} to display invoice created date. But it displaying 2015-05-25 13:30:55 . I need to only display date as 25 JUL 2015. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, go through [this][1] , good luck :)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728937/magento-how-to-get-current-date-in-magento-email-template

Answer (score 4):

You can rewrite or copy the code from `Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php` to local folder and add the below function

```
public function getInvoiceDate()
    {
        $createdAt = $this->getCreatedAt();
        $invoiceDate = date('d M Y', strtotime($createdAt));
        return $invoiceDate;
    }
```

In invoice email template, get the date as `{{var invoice.getInvoiceDate()}}`.
Like this you can add any number of functions and get from email templates

Answer (score 1):

Please note that in addition to Adarsh' answer, the `getCreatedAtFormated()`-method is only applied to the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`-object. So in order to make use if it in an **invoice** e-mail, you need to use:

```
{{var invoice.getOrder().getCreatedAtFormated('medium')}}
```

Unfortunately this will still show the time.

Comment: This is wrong. Not necessarily order and invoice have the same date. You cannot show the wrong data in the invoice.

Answer (score 0):

For formatting date in email template use following line:

```
{{var order.created_at('medium')}}
```

See following function in `/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php`

```
/**
 * Get formated order created date in store timezone
 *
 * @param   string $format date format type (short|medium|long|full)
 * @return  string
 */
public function getCreatedAtFormated($format)
{
    return Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($this->getCreatedAtStoreDate(), $format, true);
}
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

Since there is no date formatting function written in invoice class, you can extend the Invoice and add below code:

```
/**
     * Get formated invoice created date in store timezone
     *
     * @param   string $format date format type (short|medium|long|full)
     * @return  string
     */
    public function getCreatedAtFormated($format)
    {
        return Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($this->getCreatedAt(), $format, true);
    }
```

Now, you can call in your transactional email:

```
{{var invoice.getCreatedAtFormated(medium)}}
```